# python inheritance class functions

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-imaging-library

In [ImageDraw](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageDraw.py) module of `pillow` library, there's a helper function named `_compute_regular_polygon_vertices` (line 774).

With this code I try to use it with an inherited class, but it fails using the inherited class name:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


class Test(ImageDraw.ImageDraw):
    def my_first_method(self):
        # this works
        ImageDraw._compute_regular_polygon_vertices((50, 50, 50), 3, 0)

    def my_second_method(self):
        # this fails
        Test._compute_regular_polygon_vertices((50, 50, 50), 3, 0)


img = Image.new("L", (100, 100))
ctx = Test(img)

ctx.my_first_method()
ctx.my_second_method()
```

Does this mean class functions are restricted to initial class?

**Edit:**
@thomas What confuses me is that class functions are actually inherited:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def _private_get():
        return 0
    
class B(A):
    def get_a():
        return B._private_get()

b = B()
B.get_a()
```

Also, line 249 of [ImageDraw.py](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/ImageDraw.py) we can see `_compute_regular_polygon_vertices` without any class prefix... how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused by the module `ImageDraw` and the class `ImageDraw`. The class `ImageDraw` is implemented in the module `ImageDraw`. The method `_compute_regular_polygon_vertices` is inside the module, but not a method of the class.
So it cannot be inherited with your class.

Comment: ok! I get it... forget about the edit. Thx